# Stopwatch startup issues

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I've got a c# program that tests a sort algorithm and it's performance by using a instance of the Stopwatch class. 
So far everything is working correctly and I am getting the expected tick results except in the first run.
Somehow the Stopwatch class needs about 900 ticks longer for the first calculation.

Do I have to initiate the Stopwatch class somehow different or is there any way to fix this?

```
static void Main() {
    watch = new Stopwatch();

    int amount = 10; // Amount of arrays to test
    long[, ] stats= new long[3, amount]; // Array that stores ticks for every size (100,1000,10000) 'amount'-times
    for (int size = 100, iteration = 0; size <= 10000; size *= 10, iteration++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < amount; j++) {
            stats[iteration, j] = TestSort(size); // Save ticks for random tested array in stats
        }
    }
    PrintStats(stats);

}

public static long TestSort(int length) {
    int[] testArray = GenerateRandomArray(length); // Generate a random array with size of length

    watch.Reset();
    watch.Start();
    sort(testArray);
    watch.Stop();

    return watch.ElapsedTicks;
}

public static void PrintStats(long[, ] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++) {
        Console.Write("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++) {
            Console.Write(array[i, j]);
            if (j < array.GetLength(1) - 1) {
                Console.Write(",");
            }
        }
        Console.Write("]\n");
    }
}

// Sample output
// Note that first entry is about 900 ticks longer then the other ones with size 100
[1150,256,268,262,261,262,263,261,263,262]
[19689,20550,20979,22953,19913,20578,19693,19945,19811,19970]
[1880705,1850265,3006533,1869953,1900301,1846915,1840681,1801887,1931206,2206952]
```

Comment: Usually, this is either a JIT step (compiling the IL code in the method on the fly),a garbage collection run, or a busy CPU context-switching away from your process for a few cycles. Benchmarking is **hard** to get right. If it's consistently the first entry that's off, it's probably JIT, in which case you can help with this by running your benchmark code twice and throwing away the first run. But there's still all kinds of stuff going in a computer that can screw with your results.

Comment: You definitely don't have to do something special for `Stopwatch` to work. Instead, your code is obviously slower on the first iteration. That's why you normally will do a "warm up" run. In your case it might be JIT compiling or perhaps `GenerateRandomArray` that perhaps does some static one-time initialization.

Comment: Thanks, @JoelCoehoorn, and yeah it was the first entry everytime. Poorly there is no "real" fix this this but I now fixed it with "pre"-running it.

Comment: Doing a throw-away pwarmup pass is essential in any benchmarking - even without a JIT. Things need to get loaded, page faults need to get out of the way, etc

Comment: it is normal.... the first time code executes a lot of things happen like reference loading etc.